# Spring MVC - ajax integration pageContext.request.contextPath not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass data to the controller using Ajax. But there is a problem with the URL property I think. When I clicked the buttonHello, ajax is working but in the error fuction, er parameter returns "NOT FOUND".

I think something is wrong with url property because controller class is not called.
I tried other options like '/memorize/result/helloajax', etc.
The value of ${pageContext.request.contextPath} is /springcrud

My Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonHello').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/memorize/result/helloajax',
            success : function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            },
            error:function(data,status,er) { 
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/main.js" />"></script>

<title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<input type="button" value="Hello" id="buttonHello">
<div id="result"></div>
</html>
```

ResultController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/result")
public class ResultController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/helloajax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/helloajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String helloajax(){
        return "Hello Ajax";
    }
}
```

And my Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springcrud</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
                
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springcrud</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/memorize/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springcrud-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you look at the value of ${pageContext.request.contextPath} ? What is it ?

Comment: Yes I looked. /springcrud is the value of ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Comment: If you call /springcrud/memorize/result/helloajax with a post resquest, is your controller called.

You can use curl to test it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong if I try it using form element like that: <c:url var="addAction" value="/memorize/result/helloajax" /><form action="${addAction}" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> Controller is called when I did this. However when I use ajax, controller is not being called.

Comment: So we are sure that's the ajax request is wrong. What 's the url when you are on the login.jsp ?

Comment: The url on the login.jsp is http://localhost:8080/springcrud/memorize/users/login

Comment: Ok, just try url : '../result/helloajax' to see what's the result. Try after url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/memorize/result/helloajax'

Comment: When I directly call the http://localhost:8080/springcrud/memorize/result/helloajax url, everthing works fine. Controller method is called and other GET method worked. And printed just index to the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83191/discussion-between-b-k-and-elthum).